# referring to nvarchar(max) in stored procedure parameter in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm using Access and SqlServer. I had a table field "inv_base64_code" and type nvarchar(max)

```vb
 cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@p_inv_base64_code", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, Nz(!inv_base64_code, ""))
```

How could I refer to max length in vba `cmd.Parameter` because 500 not enough even 8000 not enough sometimes?

Comment: If I remember correctly, using `-1` for the max length *should* work, but I don't have an official source to back this up (hence only a comment).

Comment: Why would 8000 not be enough? Source says max for Nvarchar is 4000 https://www.tutorialscan.com/sql/difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar/#:~:text=A%20Varchar%20can%20stores%20maximum%208000

Comment: @June7: That limit is only for `[n]varchar(someNumber)`. `[n]varchar(max)` (= the successor of `[n]text`) is something completely different and can store up to 2GB.

Comment: as per Saudi Arabia "ZATCA" regulation this code field will handle all invoice data encrypted in base 64 , and other field will contain all XML invoice text encoded in 64 , some invoices header and detail exceed 10000 char

Comment: @AhmedAboelez: So, did -1 work?

Comment: @Heinzi yes work with no error  Thank You Sir